# How to pass a variable from WordPress button or link to dyanmically fill field in a gravity form

Tags: wordpress, forms, dynamic, gravity

I created a signup button on each event on a page that links to a single form and dynamically fills in the hidden title field so that when we view the submissions from an CSV that the WordPress system we have a way to sort by the event.

The problem we had is when we pass that variable via the URL, people figured out they could signup by going to another open event and change the event to a closed one in the URL and signup.

Is there a way to "hide" or pass that title as a variable so that it can still dynamically fill that hidden field?